# How does vundle treat breaking changes if uses configuration with links to git repositories?

Tags: git, vim, vundle

If I do `:PluginUpdate`, how could I be sure developers of the plugins listed in `.vimrc` as links to git repositories have not updated their repositories with breaking changes?

For example, I am using link to the repository `Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'` and I don't want this dependency to introduce breaking changes on the next upgrade.

In general, does development of vim plugins entail convention of not putting breaking changes into the latest `master` branch? I doubt such convention exist, but still, is there kind of policy for vim plugins to avoid breaking configuration with plugins upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you have to trust the plugin developer on this one.

- Most plugins have a *changelog* in some form; ideally, you would check that *before* the update (but doing that would reduce the automation benefits of `:PluginUpdate`). If you notice that a plugin got broken, manual upgrade steps should be found in the changelog, and help you to quickly resolve the problem.
- Some plugins tag releases or offer a `stable` branch for tested official releases. Using that as the basis for the update should greatly reduce the opportunities for regressions caused by using intermediate development snapshots.
- Ideally, there would be separate `stable/major-version` branches, and the plugin would follow [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org), so you're guaranteed to only receive compatible changes automatically, and switching to a new incompatible version would be a manual, controlled step.